# Not able to copy or delete items form pen drive

Tags: windows-7

When I want to download any file from Internet and try to transfer it to my pen Drive I'm unable to do so. Also I'm not able to delete the files form the pen drive as well.

Comment: What? Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: You should give some efforts to read the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) which will help you to ask a good question.

Comment: Also are you getting any type of error like `Disk is write protected`

Comment: @Nima I think now you can understand it easily :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite messy, but probably your flash drive is corrupted.

Open Computer, right click your drive -> properties -> tools -> check drive for errors

**Always 'safety remove' before removing the drive**